# Mobile Photo Gallery App

Tags: javascript, touch, gallery

I have to make a photo gallery for a mobile phone app, where I can swipe from one picture to another. Here is an [example](http://www.photoswipe.com/latest/examples/04-jquery-mobile.html#Gallery1).

unfortunately I can't use this library, because I need an inertial scrolling effect in fullscreen and you should be able to pinch to zoom in.

Any help? How should I make it? Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://swipejs.com

Comment: i can't get it work on mobile. it won't even display. do you have a showcase of this, which works on mobile or a code sample?

Comment: The homepage of SwipeJS works just fine on iOS and Android phones I have access to. Are you trying to combine it with any other JS libraries you haven't told us about?

Comment: i use swipe js just in combination with jquery

Comment: No issues with jQuery (or Zepto) but I've seen reports of people running into conflicts when using jQuery Mobile.

Answer (score 1):

You may try **[Galleria](http://galleria.io/)** or pick one from **[5 jQuery Mobile Gallery Plugins](http://www.jquery4u.com/mobile/5-jquery-mobile-gallery-plugins/)**